# How to apply lifecycle rules to a single folder of a gcs bucket in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-storage, lifecycle, terraform-provider-gcp, gsutil

New to Terraform. I am trying to add a deletion policy to a `single folder of a Google Cloud Storage bucket` in Terraform, so that when it's a few days old, just go ahead and delete it. I can only find lifecycle rules applied to the entire bucket in terraform. Retention policy, and cache time won't help with a gcs resource or object. The other way I can think of is using the `matchesPrefix` option with `gsutil` but I think this means I have to run a `local-exec` provisioner in terraform which is frowned upon as a last resort by Terraform. I don't want all the folders in a bucket to have the same policy, as I want to apply specific rules to each. Any advice or direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: I see no way how this is something terraform can help you with ... you should NOT lean on terraform for any type of deletion policy ... if your cloud of choice only provides lifecycle rules that apply to the entire bucket then split what you need into multiple buckets ... and yes anything is possible with a `local-exec` ...

Comment: If you don't want all the folders in a bucket to have the same policy and google cloud does not offer it at the moment, I would recommend reaching out to them and see what they have to say.

Comment: The matchesPrefix feature release is pretty new (less than 1 month!), the terraform could not yet be up to date. Wait or contribute!

Comment: Great advice! Thank you both. One thought was to create a separate bucket entirely - so thanks for confirming this option. I'll reach out to to the gcs terraform team and get more insight on matchesPrefix! I won't push local/remote-exec.

Comment: I have posted Helder sepulveda comments as an answer, so that others could spot the workaround easier. Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle management  can only be defined at the level of an entire bucket.It's not possible to configure lifecycle management for less than an entire bucket.

As  @Helder Sepulveda mentioned you should NOT lean on terraform for any type of deletion policy . If your cloud of choice only provides lifecycle rules that apply to the entire bucket then split what you need into multiple buckets ... and yes anything is possible with a local-exec ..

If you don't want all the folders in a bucket to have the same policy and google cloud does not offer it at the moment, I would recommend reaching out to them and see what they have to say. You may contact google cloud team from [here](https://cloud.google.com/contact)